# Згідний чи згодний?

Tags: вибір-слова

Кожен у своєму житті давав згоду на щось, погоджувався з кимось. В українській мові для цього існує два слова  — *згідний* та *згодний*, які нібито є абсолютними відповідниками. Але деколи, все-таки, ми не можемо вживати слово "*згодний*"  — "...згідно з законом" чи "...згідно з наказом". Чи може слово *"згодний"* таки не варто вживати? У яких випадках доцільно вживати "згодний" та "згідний"? І чи можна використовувати слово "*згоден*"?

Comment: Шукайте слова для перевірки, однокореневі слова. Наприклад, справи погоджують (а не «погіджують»), рішення узгоджують (а не «узгіджують»), отримують згоду (а не «згіду»).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Від Лесі до Андруховича або від Лесі до Шкляра.

### І все це через Довженка.

#### 1. [Згідний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35261&page=1119)

1. Те саме, що **зго́дний**. Я не **згідна** з тим, щоб для розуміння чиїх-небудь віршів треба знати життєпис автора (**Леся Українка**); Перед тим як попрощатися, він завжди підходить до неї з винуватим виглядом, знявши шапку і намагаючись здаватися в усьому з нею **згідним**, промовляє одну й ту ж фразу: “Ну, прощай, стара!” (**О. Довженко**); Я **згідний** відносно Пряшева, але в ньому мені довелося намотати безліч кругів навколо автовокзалу, і це був майже розпач (**Ю. Андрухович**).
2. з чим. Відповідний до чого-небудь. – Головна річ: .. поставити питання і дати на нього відповідь, згідну зі звісними нам фактами (І. Франко);
3. діал. Придатний, корисний. До того дожурюся, що не згідна буду ні людям, ні собі (Ганна Барвінок).

#### 2. [Згодний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35340&page=1121)

1. Який дає, виявляє згоду (у 1 знач.). [Паріс:] Слухай, сестро, як ти мене затримала для того, щоб я такі слова приймав від тебе, то я на те не **згоден** (**Леся Українка**);  Він повернувся швидко і повідомив, що генерал **згодний** прийняти делегацію (Ю. Смолич); // у знач. вставн. сл. – Ви недооцінюєте нашу скромну працю. Так, вона брудна, **згоден**, але я ще ні на кого не впливав силовими методами (В. **Шкляр**).
2. з ким – чим. Який має однакові з кимось погляди, дотримується того самого способу дії; солідарний з ким-небудь у чомусь. [Павло:] Якщо Яким **згоден** у речах **з** Терешком, то я становлю парубоцтву відро горілки (М. Кропивницький);

### Висновок

Отже, за найновішим повним тлумачним СловникомУМ-20, всі три слова (згідний, згодний і згоден) є літературними, ними можна користуватися без засторог.

### Коментар

Абсолютними відповідниками ці слова є тільки по першому значенню, але, як ви слушно завважили, у значенні відповідності до чого-небудь "згодний" використовувати не можна.

Answer (score 10):

Обидва слова присутні у Словнику української мови online. Томи 1-8

> **[ЗГОДНИЙ, ЗГОДЕН](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35327&page=1120)** **1**. Який дає, виявляє згоду (у 1 знач.).Наш воротар тільки мовчки потакував, – ми були згодні на все
> (Ю. Яновський); Родичі переказали, що Лукіян Середа згоден віддати за
> Грицька дочку (А. Головко); **2.** з ким – чим. Який має однакові з
> кимось погляди, дотримується того самого способу дії; солідарний з
> ким-небудь у чомусь. Якщо Яким згоден у речах з Терешком, то я
> становлю парубоцтву відро горілки (М. Кропивницький);
>
> **[ЗГІДНИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35261&page=1119)** **1.** Те саме, що ***зго́дний***. Я не згідна з тим, щоб для розуміння чиїх-небудь віршів треба знати життєпис автора (Леся
> Українка) **2**. з чим. Відповідний до чого-небудь. – Головна річ: ..
> поставити питання і дати на нього відповідь, згідну зі звісними нам
> фактами (І. Франко)**3.** діал. Придатний, корисний.

Можемо використовувати обидва слова.

Answer (score 2):

Олександр Пономарів

> Валентина Олексіївна хоче з'ясувати, як правильно казати: я згідна чи
> я згодна.
>
> У такому випадку кажемо: я згоден або я згодний, я згодна. А у вислові
> копія з оригіналом згідна вживаємо саме цієї форми.

[Джерело](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-43320813)

Відповідні висновки можна також зробити з джерела нижче.

Великий тлумачний словник української мови. Бусел. 2005.

> Згідний
>
> 1. Те саме, що згодний.
> 2. До чого і з чим.
> 3. Придатний, корисний.
>
> Згодний
>
> 1. Який дає, виявляє згоду у 1 значенні.
> 2. Який має однакові з кимось погляди, дотримується того самого способу дії.

Якщо дослідити Етимологічний словник української мови А-Г. Том 1. 1982 рік, то там теж можна побачити різницю. Тобто слова мають певне спільне значення, але й одночасно мають своє.

Сторінка 544.

> Год.
>
> Згідний - згодний, відповідний, придатний.
>
> Згодний - який дає згоду, придатний.

Подібність можна також побачити і в парі годний та гідний. Які мають різні і дещо схожі значення.

Не зміг знайти різницю в значенні слів згоден і згодний. Але знайшов цікавий текст щодо цього який може щось пояснити.

Українська граматика 1917 року

> Прикметник.
> 278. Первісно відміняли ся, як речівники і кінчали ся в номінативі одн. м. р. на ъ, в ж.р. на а, в серед. р. на о: здоров(ъ), здоров-а,
> здоров-о, повен (плънъ), повн-а, повн-о і відміняли ся як іменники
> муж. або жін. роду. Така деклінація прикметників зві ся іменною,
> відрізняючись від займенникової, якої кінцівки постали з кінцівок
> відмінків ї, я, є: здоров-ъ+ї=здоровий, здоров-а+я=здоров-а,
> здоров-о+є=здоров-е.
>
> Іменна деклінація за часи прадавні вже вийшла з
> ужитку, замінившись займенниковою, але багато форм її залишило ся в
> язиці і вживає ся або як прикметники, або як прислівники.

Comment: Ділова українська мова, на відміну від літературної, зобов'язує уникати суржику і для кожного окремого випадку вживати влучні українські відповідники і я навів вам приклади: копія з оригіналом не згідна, а збігається; однакові документи тотожні.